# enable vibration on receiving calls ubuntu touch

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

How can I enable vibration on receiving calls in ubuntu touch. I have the latest stable version installed in my nexus 4. But it didn't have an option to enable the same in settings or anywhere.
I found this link but didn't helped.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1232350

Comment: Please edit and improve your question, by telling us what you already have tried. Are you able to open/enter the phone settings? If yes: Isn't there any option to enable/disable vibration settings. If there is: Can't you change the vibration setting, or did you change it and it has no effect?

Comment: @v2r I just updated the question. I thought it's known that there is no option in the settings as I have mentioned it is the stable version installed.

Comment: The more information the better to rule out an eventuality and therefore better for solving an individual problem. Thanks for the update (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only limited options available with the stable version. I tried the develop version and amazed! It is awesome. Gone so much further than stable version. Give a try by connecting your phone to pc and running this command.

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel
```

you will be switched to the develop channel and I bet you will gonna surprised after reboot. Most of the error are fixed also. Vibration options are also available with it. But remember, it is not stable. So expect the unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option on stable (trusty) channel. I suggest you change channel to ubuntu-rtm.

Connect your device to your ubuntu pc through usb. Then open a terminal and run

`sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09`

After your device has rebooted go to system settings -> sound

Comment: already switched to develop version and everything is fine now. thanks.